# Contains filter search doesn't work for devexpress gridview c#

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I have a grid view column called `LineNumber` i set the `autofiltercondition` to `contains` .as you can see here :

[image]

But it doesn't work in running as you can see .and i have to enter the whole `linenumber` to find it .
[image]

Should i set something else property ?as you can see i have to enter `1.1/2...` to find the line,but i need something like this `%my text%`  in sqlserver

Comment: I guess you could use ADO.NET Filter for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through documentation of [AutoFilterCondition Enumeration](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsAutoFilterConditionEnumtopic)

> Enumerates the comparison operator types for the filter conditions
>   created for specific columns via the [automatic filtering row](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/CustomDocument1428.aspx).

This will work if you have either enabled AutoFilter Row functionality or filter criteria in code.

For the [FilterPopupMode Enumeration](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsFilterPopupModeEnumtopic) - 
Contains values that specify the filter dropdown style for grid columns.

You have set it to `CheckedList`, So the filter dropdown is represented as a checked list of filter items. In this mode, an end-user can select more than one item simultaneously. When the dropdown window is closed by clicking the OK button, the View will display those records that contain the checked values

Hope this information help you..

References:
[Autofilter Contains](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q182401)
[AutoFilter Row problem with LIKE conditions](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B222141)

Comment: So Can i set contains for list box ?

Comment: As per documentation, you can select items from the list but that contains filter may not work in this popup list as much i figure out about the behaviour..

Comment: You know my user should be able to select multi items from the list box .how can i use multi select with contains filter ?

Comment: I think it is not possible to combine these two functionality in popup filter list..If you want some customization help then contact DevExpress support for this..